# Selenium find_elements_ from a tag (xpath or css)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-crawler

I want to scrape prices with Selenium (Python) from a website (i am a beginner). I recognized that the price is not always in the same html tags and those are the following tags in which is the price stored:

First option:

```
<strong class="
price
scarcity_color
" data-et-click="">
<b>
€&nbsp;999
</b>
</strong>
```

Second option:

```
<b class="sr_gs_price_total">
€&nbsp;999
</b>
```

Third option:

```
<div class="
totalPrice totalPrice_no-rack-rate entire_row_clickable" data-link="/hotel/de/adlon_berlin.de.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaDuIAQGYAQe4AQfIAQ_YAQHoAQH4AQuIAgGoAgO4AprH5OYFwAIB&amp;sid=d730f1bbb7d4c57cc4185f54d3c12d41&amp;all_sr_blocks=6096409_97405530_4_2_0&amp;checkin=2019-05-23&amp;checkout=2019-05-24&amp;dest_id=-1829149&amp;dest_type=city&amp;fcpilot=0&amp;group_adults=4&amp;group_children=0&amp;hapos=13&amp;highlighted_blocks=6096409_97405530_4_2_0&amp;hpos=13&amp;req_adults=4&amp;req_children=0&amp;room1=A%2CA%2CA%2CA&amp;sr_order=popularity&amp;srepoch=1558637992&amp;srpvid=95ff85944d0201f3&amp;ucfs=1&amp;from=searchresults#maxotelRoomArea" data-target="_blank">
Preis für 4 Erwachsene
für 1 Nacht:
€&nbsp;999
<div class="prd-taxes-and-fees-under-price on-srpage-group blockuid-" data-excl-charges-raw="" data-cur-stage="1"> einschließlich Steuern und Gebühren </div> 
</div>
```

Fourth option:

```
<b class="sr_gs_price_total">
€&nbsp;999
</b>
```

Fifth option:

```
<label class="tpi_price_label tpi_price_label__orange">€&nbsp;999</label>
```

I want to just extract the price (number 999). I tried it with css selector, for example with the following code:

```
content.find_elements_by_css_selector('.price')
```

But i dont even get this price. How can i access those prices? Thank you!

Comment: if you have fifth situations then create code which tries `find_elements` with first selector, if you don't get price then tries `find_elements` with second selector, etc. If you get exception then use `try/except` to catch it.

Comment: Is this all from the same site? It seems like you are not getting the same price in all these different situations if it is one site. Post the URL of the site with the 5 different examples

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you well, you can use this xpath //*[contains(text(),'nbsp')]
I don't know much about python but in Java, I would do something like this,

*I changed my answer is very similar to Padma's answer, only don't works with your third option

```
List<WebElement> prices = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'price')]"));
           for(WebElement element : prices)
           {
           String innerText= element.getText();

           innerText = innerText.replaceAll("\\D", "");
           }
```

Comment: looks like all the classes contain "price" too.  Might be a bit more specific that way:

Comment: First of all, thank you! I can find elements with "//*[contains(text(),'nbsp')]" but when i will print them i will get the following: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="eb6d738a6acbc45b168bb3f87bdc6ff1", element="0.9276971074045848-31")>


Then i tried to get the text with .text (in Python, or in Java: .getText()) but then the string is empty... How can i access the text?

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of elements with cssSelector and then loop it to get the innerText

```
List<WebElement> textInWebElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'price')]"));
for(WebElement element : textInWebElement)
{
String innerText= element .getText();

innerText = innerText.replace("€&nbsp;", "");

}
```